# I'm looking for a "upload and save to server via link" php file

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I know one way to upload files to the server, but it involves the client uploading a file from their device. I need a file that grabs a file from another website, and saves it to a designated folder on my server. Please do not regard this as asking for code. Im am simply asking for a tweaked version of my existing code.

Comment: Then post your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for php [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) it allows you to download from any url.

```
$link = curl_init();

curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/example.jpg");
curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_exec($link);
```

Comment: Please post a code example rather than just a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to achieve this.

Pass the url from your webpage to the server and pass that url to this function. This will do the job. something like below:

```
$content = @file_get_contents($url);
    if($content === FALSE) {
        echo "Error:Invalid Url";
    }
    else {
        file_put_contents($data, $content);
        if(filesize($data) > 10485760) {
            echo "Error: File exceeds 10MB limit";
        }
        else {

        $imageinfo= getimagesize($data);

        ## Check if file is actually a image
        if($imageinfo !== false) {
           ## Do processing here
        }
```

Comment: This works, but isn't very configurable.  It is generally recommended to use curl instead.

Comment: @Brad, you are right, but i find it more convenient :).